# How to unmarshal json in golang when left part is a number

Tags: json, go

I'd like to unmarshal a json like this in the code. But this code doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thx!

PS. playground here http://play.golang.org/p/m2f94LY_d_

```
package main

import "encoding/json"
import "fmt"

type Response struct {
    Page int
    One  string "1"
}

func main() {
    in := []byte(`{"page":1, "1":"this is 1"}`)
    res := &Response{}
    json.Unmarshal(in, &res)
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the json library what the json field names are:

```
type Response struct {
    Page int `json:"page"`
    One  string `json:"1"`
}
```

Live: http://play.golang.org/p/CNcvQMqBGD

Comment: Thank you! I forgot the quotes :(